# Using $scope in a function in service angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know the same kind of question has been asked on SO many times, but I couldn't find the exact question that matches my requirement. So here's my question:

I have a function in my controller:

```
showPNG = function() {
        var pngPromise = $modal({
            template: 'index.html',
            persist: true,
            show: false,
            backdrop: 'static',
            scope: $scope,
            modalClass: 'preview-png'
        });
        $q.when(pngPromise).then(
            function(pngElement) {
                pngElement.modal('show');
            }
        );
};
```

I have 3 controllers having the same function. So I'm trying to refactor it in such a way that it is written in some service and can be called from all the controllers. What I've done so far is:

**In Service:**

```
var service = module.exports =   function ($modal, $q) {
        return {
            showPNG : function(scope) {
                var pngPromise = $modal({
                    template: 'index.html',
                    persist: true,
                    show: false,
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    scope: scope,
                    modalClass: 'preview-png'
                });
                $q.when(pngPromise).then(
                    function(pngElement) {
                        pngElement.modal('show');
                    }
                );
            }
        };
};
service.$inject = ['$modal', '$q'];
```

**In Controller:**

```
...
    myService.showPNG($scope);
...
```

This code works without any error. But the question is, can passing `$scope` as an argument to a function is service cause any side effects? Is there any better alternate to this approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against passing $scope to the service. This makes your service dependent on the controller that is using it. What if another controller needed to use the service?

Instead, have the service return a promise, and in the controller do something like the following:

```
.controller("ctrl1", ["$scope", "service", function($scope, service){
   $scope.showModal = false;
   service.showPNG()
      .then(function(shouldShow){
         $scope.showModal = shouldShow;
         $scope.$apply(); // assuming showPNG is async
      });
}]);
```

**EDIT**:
Here's an example of how a modal dialog service could be implemented: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/building-an-angularjs-modal-service